# How to post a task on a celery-rabbitmq queue in PHP?

Tags: php, python, rabbitmq, celery

I have below versions of celery and rabbitmq installed -

> celery 3.1.6 
>   rabbitmq 3.1.1

I can post a task to the default queue from PHP -

```
//client.php
<?php
require 'celery-php/celery.php';
$c = new Celery('localhost', 'guest', 'guest', '/');
$result = $c->PostTask('tasks.add', array(2,2));
```

My worker module is in python -

```
# tasks.py
from celery import Celery
celery = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//')
@celery.task(queue='demo', name='add')
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I run the celery worker and client like this -

```
# terminal window 1
$ celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
# terminal window 2
$ php -f client.php
```

This works. I see below output in terminal window 1 :

```
Received task: tasks.add[php_52b1759141a8b3.43107845]
Task tasks.add[php_52b1759141a8b3.43107845] succeeded in 0.000701383920386s: 4
```

But I want to have different queues. For a demonstration, let's say I only want one queue called **demo**. So I run my celery worker like this -

```
$ celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info -Q demo
```

But it's not working. The task is not getting executed. I guess it's probably because PHP code is posting the task on default queue : **celery** (apparently not on **demo** queue).

How do I post my task on a particular queue in PHP? Please help.

Comment: I guess I am gonna have go with different tasks instead of different queues if above thing is not possibile.

Comment: You should check the source code of celery-php to see if there is a way to specify the `exchange` and `routing_key` of the task.  In amqp you don't send messages to queues, you send them to exchanges which will then deliver the message to queues by matching the routing_key.  There is a trick: you can set `exchange=""` and routing_key to the name of a queue (e.g. `routing_key="demo"` and it will deliver the message directly to the demo queue, bypassing the routing layer.

Comment: I am not that familiar with amqp. I'll go thorough the source code of celery-php and try above things. I'll let you know about it. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, your PHP client for Celery takes the queue name as "celery".

In order to change the queue to publish to, you must specify the queue name while instantiating a connection to Celery. 
So, if you are starting your Celery worker with "-Q demo" option, then your connection to Celery in PHP should be -

```
$exchange = 'demo'; 
$binding = 'demo'; 
$c = new Celery('localhost', 'guest', 'guest', '/', $exchange, $binding);
```

Note: With -Q option, the exchange and routing_key value is same as queue_name.

Please try this and share the results.

**About exchange and binding** :

With analogy to Telephone Services, Exchange is like "Telephone Operator", whose only job is to "Direct the call to YOU" with the help of routing_key.

Binding is then "Your Telephone Number", which acts as routing_key to your telephone.

**Note** : This process where exchange is redirecting the incoming message to the queue based on binding (routing_key), is a DIRECT exchange type. 
AMQP has few other types of exchanges, which you can read in AMQP documentation.

You can also refer this [Celery page](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#exchanges-queues-and-routing-keys)